# Forwarding writable received in map/reduce

Tags: hadoop

Is there any reason why you shouldn't forward the writable received in map/reduce function?

What I mean by that - each map/reduce function has a key/value writable and possibly emits a key/value pair. In case if I want to perform some filtering, should I just emit the received writable, or there's some reason to create another writable, set it's values from received writable and then emit it?

Comment: Implement filtering logic in Mapper itself and emit filtered data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure if I got it right, so I could use same writables?

Comment: You should write to Writable after filtering the data in Mapper class. Example at : https://github.com/rajdeepd/hadoop-samples/blob/master/java/filter-mapper-example/src/main/java/com/hadoop/example/FilterMapper.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason of creating a new writable. This can be seen in default [Reducer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.java) available with Hadoop.